# Find if array does not contain a value after str.split()

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I have a pandas series that look like this

```
(us20160223054)\nname=delmar systems, inc. , city=broussard , state=la , country=us \n\n(us9625004)\nname=delmar systems, inc. , city=broussard , state=la , country=us , atyp=us company \n\n(wo201542218)\nname=delmar systems, inc. p.o. box 129 broussard, la 70518 , postcode=70518 , country=us \n
```

Sample array = [a,a,b,a]

What I want to do is after using split('\n\n'), I want to return rows that contain a specific word that appears at least once but not the entire array.For example, for this series, lets say the wordToSearch = broussard, this will be False since broussard appears inside all elements of the array. If you look at the sample array, and the wordToSearch = a, it will be true since 'a' appears at least once but it is not in the entire array.

I tried using test[~test['assignee_address'].str.split('\n\n').str.contains('houston')]
but it does not work since str.split does not search the entire array

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please show a code sample of what you already tried, so the community can help you to find the error and fix it.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is after applying your `.split("\n\n")`, search for the existence of the word in every string inside the array, if it happens at least once, it is inside that array:

```
text = [['xxx'], ['bbb'], ['aaa'], ['vasco']] #after .split()
for wordArray in text:
  contains = True in [('wordToSearch' in string) for string in wordArray] # search for word in every element, if one is true, then you found it
  if contains == True:
    # do something
```